# how to I change CCArray type to SpriteFrame?

Tags: c++, ios, coco2d-x

The error lies in

```
CCAnimation *_runAnim = CCAnimation::createWithSpriteFrames(zoewalkingFrames, 0.1);
```

this line, when I'm trying to pass CCArray zoewalkingFrames to CCAnimation _runAnim, the log says "Reference to type 'const Vector could not bind to an lvalue of type 'CCArray' aka '"here, so what should I do so I can pass the CCArray var to SpriteFrame? Thanks

```
#include "ZoeAnime.h"
using namespace cocos2d;
bool ZoeAnime::init()
{
if ( !Node::init() )
{
    return false;
}

auto spritecache = SpriteFrameCache::getInstance();
spritecache->addSpriteFramesWithFile("zoeanime.plist");

CCSpriteBatchNode *_spritesheet = CCSpriteBatchNode::create("zoeanime.png");
this->addChild(_spritesheet);

CCArray* zoewalkingFrames = CCArray::create();
for(int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    CCString* filename = CCString::createWithFormat("zoewalking%0d.png", i);
    CCSpriteFrame* frame = CCSpriteFrameCache::sharedSpriteFrameCache()->spriteFrameByName(filename->getCString());
    zoewalkingFrames->addObject(frame);
}

CCAnimation *_runAnim = CCAnimation::createWithSpriteFrames(zoewalkingFrames, 0.1);
CCSprite* zoe = CCSprite::createWithSpriteFrameName("zoewalking01.png");

CCSize winsize = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getWinSize();
zoe->setPosition(ccp(winsize.width*0.5, winsize.height*0.5));

CCAction* action = CCRepeatForever::create(CCAnimate::create(_runAnim));

zoe->runAction(action);
_spritesheet->addChild(zoe);
return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a good one for reference, just replace CCArray with Vector data type.

http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/erro-sprite-createwithspriteframes/16887